# Lost linebreaks in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, console, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome's console (Tools » Developer Tools) the script I'm debugging is showing up without linebreaks even though the actual file has them. This has happened to me before, but I can figure out if it's something with the spaces in the file or a setting in Chrome. But it's pretty impossible to debug something when every error comes up as being on line 1. I tried restarting Chrome but no dice. Any idea how to get it back to normal?

Comment: have you tried it with firebug?

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez It's fine in Firebug in Firefox. But I want Chromeness ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your file with Notepad or some other editor and save it again. It seems like you ran into the same problem as the one mentioned here.

http://196.23.168.153/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=0936a4d8f8b915b5&hl=en

If that doesn't work, use the pretty print button :-)

Comment: Just fyi, it looks like that URL is too old now and doesn't show the forum message anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the file has been minified. Do you know if it's run through any kind of build process before you're looking at it?

If not, I'm not sure exactly why that might be happening. There is a halfway decent workaround:

Open the script in the Scripts tab, and click the `{}` prettyprint button at the bottom to restore the formatting. It's kind of annoying to have to do that all the time, though.

Is there a public link we could see? I can imagine that there might be some line-ending issues if the file was created on one platform (Mac/Linux/Windows) and is being viewed on another. Haven't run into this one myself yet.

Comment: Thx, nah it's not minified. That button didn't do it, but it'good to know about. :]

Comment: Copying it to to a new file fixed it.

Comment: I'm not sure what caused it but I had done a find and replace from tabs to spaces. But I do that all the time so I don't know if that was it or not.

Comment: I doubt it was the find and replace. Weird. Glad you got it worked out, though. :)

Comment: I think the line-endings did it even though I would expect Chrome to handle the UNIX newlines correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was the EOL line endings. I changed them from Mac Classic (\n) to Windows Dos (\n\r).